# MSG Command on CMD result Error 5 getting session names

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, cmd.exe

I have 2 computer connected over LAN. Both has windows 10 pro version 1607. I open cmd from 1 computer and try to use message command like this :

```
msg * /server:lenovo-pc "Hello"
```

Lenovo-pc is other computer name. The command result **Error 5 getting session names**

How to fix this problem ?

- I already set the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\AllowRemoteRPC from 0 to 1 and already restart.
- I already run cmd with level admin.
- Network discovery, file and printer sharing on private and public network already TURN ON on both computer.

Comment: `msg` command never worked at all for me as well

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Amit still no solution